# How to add a row of data with EPPlus when delimiter can occur inside the cells?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm having problems when my data contains my delmiter value, that the cells will be populated in the wrong place.

I'm exporting and importing excel data from my application. Below is a working snippet of my export. I've set my delimiter to be ';' but it causes issues if any of my properties value contains this character. Therefore I am wondering if there is a better way to load data which would allow me to use my delimiter value inside the cells.

```
 public void Export()
        {
            using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
                var headerRow = new List<string[]>()
                {
                    new string[] { "Id", "FirstName", "LastName",  }
                };
                // Determine the header range (e.g. A1:D1)
                string headerRange = "A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 64) + "1";
                var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"];
                worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);
                worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 20.0;

                //TODO examine delimiter 
                var counter = 2;
                var format = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat();
                format.Delimiter = ';';
                //format.TextQualifier = '"';
                format.DataTypes = new[] { eDataTypes.String };

                foreach (Attendee item in context.Attendees.Include(attendee => attendee.Tags))
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[counter++, 1].LoadFromText($"{item.Id};{item.FirstName};{item.LastName}", format);
                }

                //Create the response
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=people.xlsx");
                Response.BinaryWrite(excel.GetAsByteArray()); 
                Response.Flush(); 
                Response.End();
               }
        }
```

This works but if any of my fields contain ';' I will have problems. Is there some archaic delimiter value I can use or perhaps a more secure way to load my data? I could probably write two nested for loops and call load cell on every cell but that would be rather ugly as I have about 15 columns/fields in my real code. I cannot load from collection either as there are some fields that I don't want to show and they end up in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use cell by cell?

```
foreach (Attendee item in context.Attendees.Include(attendee => attendee.Tags))
{
    int column = 1;
    worksheet.Cells[counter, column++].Value = item.Id;
    worksheet.Cells[counter, column++].Value = item.FirstName;
    worksheet.Cells[counter++, column++].Value = item.LastName;
}
```

**edit - full code**

```
public void Export()
    {
        using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
            var headerRow = new List<string[]>()
            {
                new string[] { "Id", "FirstName", "LastName",  }
            };
            // Determine the header range (e.g. A1:D1)
            string headerRange = "A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 64) + "1";
            var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"];
            worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);
            worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 20.0;

            var counter = 2;

            foreach (Attendee item in context.Attendees.Include(attendee => attendee.Tags))
            {
                int column = 1;
                worksheet.Cells[counter, column++].Value = item.Id;
                worksheet.Cells[counter, column++].Value = item.FirstName;
                worksheet.Cells[counter++, column++].Value = item.LastName;
            }

            //Create the response
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=people.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(excel.GetAsByteArray()); 
            Response.Flush(); 
            Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried exactly this, but it would not work, it still couldn't handle my delimiter value.  I ended up specifying the delimiter as ¤ so I will have to pray that nobody uses this character.

Comment: Let's say Firstname contained kalle;fdsf, fdsf would be put in the next column anyway. Maybe its a bug in the lib?

Comment: I post the full code I have in mind.  I can't figure out why this is an issue with delimiter.

Comment: I just tested it right now.  It works without any issue;

Answer (score 0):

There is the ascii "VTAB" character (chr(11), 0x0B), that is probably safe to use as your delimiter, as you'll probably otherwise never encounter it outside of this :)

How many people really know how to hold down the ALT key (in Windows) and type "0011" on the keypad to enter that control character?